# Java sockets hangs when reading all output

Tags: java, sockets

I have a socket in Java that connects to an SMTP server to send email and uses a `BufferedReader` and a `Writer` to read and write to the socket. My problem is knowing when to terminate the `while()` loop called after writing to the socket; using

```
while(bufferedreader.readLine() != null)
```

doesn't work as if there isn't a line to read from the server the `BufferedReader` just hangs instead of returning `null`.

Comment: When does it hang ? After sending the "QUIT" command? Because it's the only (sure) moment where the server will disconnect. If you issue another command, and read until the socket closes, you automatically will block.

Comment: It's not after the quit command, it's after writing each line required to send an email.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `readLine()` when reading data from sockets since `readLine()` assumes that the incoming stream is a text file, which has line endings. This might not be the case, which would block the `readLine()` indefinitely because there's no line ending coming even though the incoming stream has ended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) messages out of the stream to figure out when to stop. For example, you need to send a `QUIT` message to the server to indicate that you are done and then catch the `221 Bye`.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend not to reinvent the wheel and to use [SMTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/smtp/SMTPClient.html) from [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) project.

Unless you're doing some research/educational work.

Comment: Sadly, it's for educational purposes so I can't go down this route :(

Answer (score 0):

You musn't use "while(bufferedreader.readLine() != null)" because what it does is read every line from the socket, and hang until something new is posted.

It won't work, except for the "QUIT" command, because for the other phases of the dialogue with the SMTP server, you need to read only a few of the lines, and then send another command, etc, etc.

Depending on the type of smtp command you run, you will expect different answers. You have to read carefully the SMTP RFC (base in 2821 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) to understand the underlying protocol.

Basically, most of the command you will send will receive a one-line answer with a result code . This code indicates what to do (read more lines, or skip to the next command).

Ex: by sending 'HELO myserver', you will expect a '250 xxx' answer (or it's a failure !).

So you just read 1 line.

By sending 'EHLO myserver', you will expect more lines, don't remember the stop condition.

etc, etc, etc...

For example, on my local EXIM I have those results:

First, read 1 line from the server, check 220

```
220 jm.localdomain ESMTP Exim 4.72 Wed, 15 Feb 2012 13:52:36 +0100
```

Then send:

```
HELO localhost
```

read and check 250 :

```
250 jm.localdomain Hello me [127.0.0.1]
```

and so on

```
MAIL FROM: me@yahoo.com
250 OK
RCPT TO: everybody@yahoo.com
250 Accepted
DATA
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
Subject: how are you?

bla
bla
bla
.
250 OK id=1RxePi-00074k-Nv
QUIT
221 jm.localdomain closing connection
```